# Filling missing dates by group

Tags: c#, sql-server, r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
shop_id,item_id,time,value
150,1,2015-07-10,3
150,1,2015-07-11,5
150,1,2015-07-13,2
150,2,2015-07-10,15
150,2,2015-07-12,12
```

Within each group, defined by "shop_id and "item_id", there are missing dates.

I wish to expand this irregular the time series to a regular, with consecutive dates, within each group:

```
shop_id,item_id,time,value
150,1,2015-07-10,3
150,1,2015-07-11,5
150,1,2015-07-12,0 # <~~ added
150,1,2015-07-13,2
150,2,2015-07-10,15
150,2,2015-07-11,0 # <~~ added
150,2,2015-07-12,12
```

For the dates which are added, the corresponding values should by zero. I've read very similar questions though (either using R or SQL coalescing), but most of the solutions I've seen doesn't involve GROUP BYs.

Basically I have access to the SQL database/I can export as CSV for manipulation preferably in C#. Was hoping to find C# libraries that can do such data manipulation but couldn't find any.

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: So do you want a [tag:R] based solution or [tag:SQL] based solution or only C#? If you do not want R then remove the tag as then this question does not involve R at all. Also, have you tried anything with C# yet? Even without a library (check out the [.NET DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606753/populating-a-dataset-from-a-csv-file)) one can open and parse a file manually

Comment: To stimulate GROUP BY in R, you could use the package *plyr* for aggregating data. Try the function *daply* ( [plyr manual, page 17](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/plyr.pdf) ).

Comment: Apologies for not being clear - actually any solutions are fine!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `data.table` from `R`.  Assuming that 'time' column is of 'Date' class,

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT1 <- setDT(df1)[, list(time=seq(min(time), max(time), by ='day')),
                    by =.(shop_id, item_id)]
setkeyv(df1, names(df1)[1:3])[DT1][is.na(value), value:=0]
#   shop_id item_id       time value
#1:     150       1 2015-07-10     3
#2:     150       1 2015-07-11     5
#3:     150       1 2015-07-12     0
#4:     150       1 2015-07-13     2
#5:     150       2 2015-07-10    15
#6:     150       2 2015-07-11     0
#7:     150       2 2015-07-12    12
```

In the devel version, you can also do this without setting the 'key'.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 df1[DT1, on =c('shop_id', 'item_id', 'time')][is.na(value), value:=0]
 #   shop_id item_id       time value
 #1:     150       1 2015-07-10     3
 #2:     150       1 2015-07-11     5
 #3:     150       1 2015-07-12     0
 #4:     150       1 2015-07-13     2
 #5:     150       2 2015-07-10    15
 #6:     150       2 2015-07-11     0
 #7:     150       2 2015-07-12    12
```

Or as @Arun suggested, a more efficient option would be

```
 DT1[, value := 0L][df1, value := i.value, on = c('shop_id', 'item_id', 'time')]
 DT1
```

Comment: Nice answer with `on`, this thing is going to rock.

Comment: After getting `DT1`, it's more efficient to do: `DT1[, value := 0L][df1, value := i.value, on= ...]`

Answer (score 3):

This is a Sql based solution

First you need a `dates` table

Date table query. Note this will create a *physical table* in your database.

```
;with cte as
(
select cast('2000-01-01' as datetime) as Dates -- Start date 
union all
select dateadd(MM,1,Dates) 
from cte 
where Dates < '2099-12-01' -- End date
)
select * 
INTO Date_table 
from CTE
```

Then you need to `left outer join` your table with `Date_table` to get the missing dates.

```
SELECT A.shop_id, 
       A.item_id, 
       DT.dates, 
       Isnull(Y.value, 0) 
FROM   date_table DT 
       CROSS JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT shop_id, 
                                  item_id 
                  FROM   yourtable) A 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable Y 
                    ON t.[time] = DT.dates 
                       AND A.shop_id = Y.shop_id 
                       AND A.item_id = Y.item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `fill_by_value` from `padr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(padr)

df %>%
  mutate(time = as.Date(time)) %>%
  group_by(item_id) %>%
  pad() %>%              # from padr
  fill(shop_id) %>%      # from tidyr
  fill_by_value(value)   # from padr
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   item_id [2]
  shop_id item_id       time value
    <int>   <int>     <date> <dbl>
1     150       1 2015-07-10     3
2     150       1 2015-07-11     5
3     150       1 2015-07-12     0
4     150       1 2015-07-13     2
5     150       2 2015-07-10    15
6     150       2 2015-07-11     0
7     150       2 2015-07-12    12
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "shop_id,item_id,time,value
150,1,2015-07-10,3
150,1,2015-07-11,5
150,1,2015-07-13,2
150,2,2015-07-10,15
150,2,2015-07-12,12", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```