# Efficient way to Fill Time-Series per group

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I was looking for a way to fill a time series data set by time, per group. The very very inefficient way I was using was to `split` the data set per group and apply a custom time-series fill function (create sequence between max and min, and merge) in all elements of that list. Needless to say, this operations would not go pass the splitting.

My dataset looks like,

> ```
>     source                 grp cnt
>  1:     83 2017-06-06 13:00:00   1
>  2:     83 2017-06-06 23:00:00   1
>  3:     83 2017-06-07 03:00:00   1
>  4:     83 2017-06-07 07:00:00   2
>  5:     83 2017-06-07 13:00:00   1
>  6:     83 2017-06-07 19:00:00   1
>  7:     83 2017-06-08 00:00:00   1
>  8:     83 2017-06-08 14:00:00   1
>  9:     83 2017-06-08 15:00:00   1
> 10:     83 2017-06-08 20:00:00   1
> 11:    137 2017-06-04 02:00:00   1
> 12:    137 2017-06-04 05:00:00   1
> 13:    137 2017-06-04 23:00:00   1
> ...
> ```

My attempt was to use `tidyverse` methods by utilising the `complete` function, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 %>% 
 group_by(source) %>% 
 complete(source, grp = seq(min(grp), max(grp), by = 'hour'))
```

However, after about 40-45 seconds, a progress bar appeared (apparently a neat feature in some tidyverse functions - I suspect `complete` in this case) which estimated 9 hours to completion. My dataset is very very big and this is not the lightest operation, so something really efficient is what I am looking for.

**DATA**

```
#dput(d1)
structure(list(source = c("83", "83", "83", "83", "83", "83", 
"83", "83", "83", "83", "137", "137", "137", "137", "137", "137", 
"137", "137", "137", "137", "137", "137", "137", "137"), grp = structure(c(1496743200, 
1496779200, 1496793600, 1496808000, 1496829600, 1496851200, 1496869200, 
1496919600, 1496923200, 1496941200, 1496530800, 1496541600, 1496606400, 
1496617200, 1496649600, 1496696400, 1496808000, 1496844000, 1496876400, 
1496962800, 1497880800, 1497888000, 1497978000, 1497996000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), cnt = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
)), .Names = c("source", "grp", "cnt"), row.names = c(NA, -24L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Related: [Fastest way to add rows for missing values in a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438969/fastest-way-to-add-rows-for-missing-values-in-a-data-frame/10473931#10473931)

Comment: @Henrik thank you for the link. I actually went through a lot of Qs about filling missing dates but no grouping was required in any of them.

Comment: Also: [Filling missing dates by group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31502628/1851712)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `data.table` is really much faster than the `tidyverse` option. So merely translating the above into `data.table`(compliments of @Frank) completed the operation in little under 3 minutes.

```
library(data.table)

mDT = setDT(d1)[, .(grp = seq(min(grp), max(grp), by = "hour")), by = source]
new_D <- d1[mDT, on = names(mDT)]

new_D <- new_D[, cnt := replace(cnt, is.na(cnt), 0)] #If needed
```

Comment: Beautiful approach. Is there any elegant solution to keep other variables _without_ using `by = `?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using zoo as well. This is an order of magnitude faster than the code and data in the question but not as fast as the data.table solution although there exists the possibility of speeding it iup further if the last line of code shown below is not needed.

We read `d1` into a zoo object `z` splitting it to give a multivariate time series having a column for each source.  We then merge that with a zero width series having all the times and fortify that back to a data frame using the `melt=TRUE` argument to get a long form data.frame.  If a wide form multivariate zoo series can be used then you could skip the last line in which case it would then be even faster.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(d1, split = 1, index = 2) # wide form
zz <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "hour"))) # expand
fortify(zz, melt = TRUE) # convert to long form data.frame
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This is a great idea spreading it! I admit my first was to convert to zoo object and go from there but couldn't quite get there with the grouping.