# r data.table building a custom rolling sum function

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently working with a data set in R that looks somewhat like the following (except with millions of pids and observations):

```
id  agedays  diar
1    1        1
1    2        0
1    3        1
1    4        1
1    5        0
1    6        0
1    7        NA
1    8        1
1    9        1
1    10       1
3    2        0
3    5        0
3    6        0
3    8        1
3    9        1
4    1        0
4    4        NA
4    5        0
4    6        1
4    7        0
```

I need to create a rolling sum on diar based on increments of agedays values. I want to create a variable that will hold the sum of diar 5 days back for each row of data. The variable will be called diar_prev5. The data set should look like the following :

```
id  agedays  diar  diar_prev5
1    1        1      NA
1    2        0      NA
1    3        1      NA
1    4        1      NA
1    5        0      3
1    6        0      2
1    7        NA     2
1    8        1      2
1    9        1      2
1    10       1      3
3    2        0      NA
3    5        0      0
3    6        0      0
3    8        1      1
3    9        1      2
4    1        0      NA
4    4       NA      NA
4    5        0      0
4    6        1      1
4    7        0      1
```

As shown above, the rolling sum should include the current agedays value and if some values in between the current row and the 4 days back contain NA values, the rolling sum should ignore these and still count the obs. in between (if there are any). I had tried both roll_sum and rollsum functions to achieve this request, but found that the function did not work if the agedays column contained gaps. When gaps occurred, the rolling sum would just contain an NA value as opposed to calculating the values in between the gaps. The functions also don't seem to include the present value of agedays in the rolling sum calculation, so I previously had to go back in and manually add this.

The previous code I used pertaining to roll_sum that did not work is seen below:

```
DT[, diar_prev5 := roll_sum(lag(diar, 1L), n=4L, fill=NA, align = "right"), by=id]
```

My question now, is how can I create a custom function to achieve the above that will include the current value of diar in the calculation and won't have issues with gaps on agedays values?

I've tried the following- but the variable results with only 0's and doesn't seem to work properly:

```
f = function(id_input, ageday_input) { 
  startday = ageday_input
  endday = ageday_input- 13
  sum((MPC_anthro %>% filter(id == id_input & agedays <= startday & startday <= endday))$diar) }

f = Vectorize(f)

MPC_anthro_1<-MPC_anthro %>% mutate(diar_prev5 = f(id, agedays))
```

Comment: One possibility would be to start here: [Fastest way to add rows for missing time steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473931/1851712), then apply `data.table::frollsum` (unclear what `roll_sum` is). Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik thanks for the suggestion! I have tried filling in the days but since the file is very large, it is wildly inefficient and takes quite a while to complete.

Comment: why is diar_prev5 = 0 on id = 3 / ageday = 5 : there are only 4 days with known values as the series start with 2. According to your calculation for id 1, shouldn't this be 0?

Comment: @Waldi it should be summing up the value of ageday==2 and ageday==5, so NA + 0. Therefore diar_prev5 should be 0. I probably didn't explain this very well, apologies. It says diar_prev5, but it should be counting the current diar value and then incrementing back 4 levels and summing up accordingly. So in total 5 days of diar are summed.

Comment: OK, thanks, see my edit : even simpler

Comment: @Waldi Solved!!! :)

Comment: OK, perfect! The solution is also not limited to agedays <= 13

Comment: yeah, should have used something like `.(agedays=1:max(agedays))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` solution using overlapping intervals instead of filling missing values :

```
DT[  ,.(id,start=agedays-4L,stop=agedays,agedays,diar)][
   DT,on=.(id=id,stop >= agedays,start <= agedays),.(id,agedays,diar),allow.cartesian=T][
     ,.(diar_prev5 = sum(diar,na.rm=T)),by = .(id,agedays)][
     ,.(id,agedays, diar_prev5 = ifelse(agedays>=5,diar_prev5,NA))]

   id agedays diar_prev5
 1:  1       1         NA
 2:  1       2         NA
 3:  1       3         NA
 4:  1       4         NA
 5:  1       5          3
 6:  1       6          2
 7:  1       7          2
 8:  1       8          2
 9:  1       9          2
10:  1      10          3
11:  3       2         NA
12:  3       5          0
13:  3       6          0
14:  3       8          1
15:  3       9          2
16:  4       1         NA
17:  4       4         NA
18:  4       5          0
19:  4       6          1
20:  4       7          1
```

The logic is better explained by running the two first steps separately:

```
DT[  ,.(id,start=agedays-4L,stop=agedays,agedays,diar)][
  DT,on=.(id=id,stop >= agedays,start <= agedays),.(id,x.start,x.stop,x.agedays,i.agedays,diar),allow.cartesian=T][order(id,x.start,i.agedays)]

    id x.start x.stop x.agedays agedays i.agedays diar
 1:  1      -3      1         1       1         1    1
 2:  1      -2      2         2       2         1    0
 3:  1      -2      2         2       2         2    0
 4:  1      -1      3         3       3         1    1
 5:  1      -1      3         3       3         2    1
 6:  1      -1      3         3       3         3    1
 7:  1       0      4         4       4         1    1
 8:  1       0      4         4       4         2    1
 9:  1       0      4         4       4         3    1
10:  1       0      4         4       4         4    1
11:  1       1      5         5       5         1    0
12:  1       1      5         5       5         2    0
13:  1       1      5         5       5         3    0
14:  1       1      5         5       5         4    0
15:  1       1      5         5       5         5    0
```

1. We create an observation window `[start = agedays-4,stop = agedays]`
2. We join the table to the observation window so that for each `ageday` we get all `i.agedays` and `diar` in the observation window
   In a `data.table` join, the terms coming from the left side of the join are prefixed by `x.` if the same name exists on the right side. The terms from the right side are prefixed by `.i`
3. the next steps just sum up all the rows in the observation window for each `ageday`

Comment: You might add the `diar` column to the output to make it easier to see how it does the rolling sum.

Comment: @Dave, I agree, the way it works isn't easy to visualize : see my edit

Comment: @ Waldi that is helpful. What I meant to suggest was that you add `diar` to the final output, like the OP did. That way it is easy to see that `diar_prev5` is in fact the correct rolling sum.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected `data.table` should be fast to fill in the missing `agedays`, even for a large dataset. So I built one with a million rows and tried the approach shown in [Filling missing dates by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502591/filling-missing-dates-by-group/31502628).

In the link @Henrik gave, you would find that he also gave this link.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(2345)
DT <- data.table(
 id=rep(1:100000,each=10),
 agedays=unlist(lapply(1:100000,function(x) sort(sample(1:13,10,replace=FALSE)))),
 diar=sample(c(0,1,NA),1e6,replace=TRUE)
 )
 
 DT1 <- DT[,.(agedays=1:max(agedays)),by=.(id)]

 DT1[,diar:=NA_integer_][DT,diar:=i.diar,on=c("id","agedays")]
 
 DT1[,diar_prev5 := frollsum(diar,5,na.rm=TRUE),by=id]

 DT2 <- DT1[DT,.(id,agedays,diar,diar_prev5),on=c("id","agedays")]
  
 head(DT2,25)
```

giving

```
        id agedays diar diar_prev5
 1:  1       1    0         NA
 2:  1       2   NA         NA
 3:  1       3    0         NA
 4:  1       4    1         NA
 5:  1       7    1          2
 6:  1       8    1          3
 7:  1      10   NA          2
 8:  1      11    1          3
 9:  1      12   NA          2
10:  1      13    1          2
11:  2       1    1         NA
12:  2       3   NA         NA
13:  2       4    0         NA
14:  2       5    0          1
15:  2       6   NA          0
16:  2       7    1          1
17:  2       8    1          2
18:  2       9   NA          2
19:  2      10    1          3
20:  2      12    1          3
21:  3       2    1         NA
22:  3       3   NA         NA
23:  3       4   NA         NA
24:  3       6    1          2
25:  3       7    0          1
    id agedays diar diar_prev5
```

It didn't take too long to run. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using rolling join:

```
n <- 5L
DT[, c("ndaysago", "val") := .(agedays - n + 1L, fcoalesce(diar, 0L))]
DT[, cs := cumsum(val), id]

DT[, diar_prev := DT[DT, on=.(id, agedays=ndaysago), roll=-n, i.cs - x.cs + x.val]]
DT[agedays - n < 0L, diar_prev := NA_integer_]
```

output:

```
    id agedays diar diar_prev5 ndaysago val cs diar_prev
 1:  1       1    1         NA       -3   1  1        NA
 2:  1       2    0         NA       -2   0  1        NA
 3:  1       3    1         NA       -1   1  2        NA
 4:  1       4    1         NA        0   1  3        NA
 5:  1       5    0          3        1   0  3         3
 6:  1       6    0          2        2   0  3         2
 7:  1       7   NA          2        3   0  3         2
 8:  1       8    1          2        4   1  4         2
 9:  1       9    1          2        5   1  5         2
10:  1      10    1          3        6   1  6         3
11:  3       2    0         NA       -2   0  0        NA
12:  3       5    0          0        1   0  0         0
13:  3       6    0          0        2   0  0         0
14:  3       8    1          1        4   1  1         1
15:  3       9    1          2        5   1  2         2
16:  4       1    0         NA       -3   0  0        NA
17:  4       4   NA         NA        0   0  0        NA
18:  4       5    0          0        1   0  0         0
19:  4       6    1          1        2   1  1         1
20:  4       7    0          1        3   0  1         1
21:  5       1    1         NA       -3   1  1        NA
22:  5       6    2          2        2   2  3         2
23:  5      10    3          5        6   3  6         5
24:  5      15    4          4       11   4 10         4
    id agedays diar diar_prev5 ndaysago val cs diar_prev
```

data with one more id:

```
DT <- fread("id  agedays  diar  diar_prev5
1    1        1      NA
1    2        0      NA
1    3        1      NA
1    4        1      NA
1    5        0      3
1    6        0      2
1    7        NA     2
1    8        1      2
1    9        1      2
1    10       1      3
3    2        0      NA
3    5        0      0
3    6        0      0
3    8        1      1
3    9        1      2
4    1        0      NA
4    4       NA      NA
4    5        0      0
4    6        1      1
4    7        0      1
5 1 1 NA
5 6 2 2
5 10 3 5
5 15 4 4")
```

Would be interested to know the runtime on your actual dataset.